# Shorthand and longhand WPF binding equivalence

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make some XAML fragments more readable (not production code, just for me to get a better understanding of XAML inner workings).
The original code is

```
   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}">
```

I've changed it to

```
<CheckBox>
   <CheckBox.IsChecked>
      <Binding Path="IsSelected" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
         <Binding.Source>
             <RelativeSource Mode="FindAncestor" AncestorType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"/>
         </Binding.Source>
      </Binding>
   </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
```

The first form works ok (it properly binds the IsChecked property of the CheckBox to the IsSelected property of the container (a DataGridRow).
The second one does not work.
How should it look to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have set  `<Binding.Source>` instead of `<Binding.RelativeSource>` in second case. If you set `<Binding.RelativeSource>` it will work too.

```
<CheckBox>
   <CheckBox.IsChecked>
      <Binding Path="IsSelected" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
         <Binding.RelativeSource>
             <RelativeSource Mode="FindAncestor" AncestorType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"/>
         </Binding.RelativeSource>
      </Binding>
   </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
```